# Virtual Box not allowing me to type. [Arch Linux]

Tags: linux, virtualbox, arch

So I downloaded a virtual box and the cyberos for it. I am trying to run `sudo pacman -S virtualbox-guest-utils`. Once this runs through, it asks for my password. When I start typing it, there is nothing on the screen. It is as if it just rejects my typing. I tried type the password using an on-screen keyboard but there is still no result.

Answer (score 0):

I've encountered this problem before with an Ubuntu. So, I've searched the problem and I've discorvered that it's a VirtualBox problem catching the keyboard input while loading the VM. So, the only thing you can do, is to shut down and restart your VM and hope that this bug won't perform. One of the most known solution is also to degrade the amount of maximum RAM your VM can use. For example, if you've got 12G of RAM, it's better if your VM can only access at a 6G of it.

This is the problem asked on the VirtualBox forum: https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=78077

Comment: Is there a way to paste in the virtual box terminal?